# Hiding @mentions from 'Latest Tweet'

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

I've set up a 'latest tweet function on a website. The client is now asking that I hide @mentions to stop them appearing as a 'latest tweet'. I've had a look at the Twitter API but, to be honest, I've very little knowledge of this and therefore can't really get my head around how to do this. Or even if it is possible.

This code I use to call the 'latest tweet' is

```
<?php
            // Your twitter username.
            $username = "****";

            // Prefix - some text you want displayed before your latest tweet.
            // (HTML is OK, but be sure to escape quotes with backslashes: for example href=\"link.html\")
            $prefix = "";

            // Suffix - some text you want display after your latest tweet. (Same rules as the prefix.)
            $suffix = "";

            $feed = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:" . $username . "&rpp=1";

            function parse_feed($feed) {
                $stepOne = explode("<content type=\"html\">", $feed);
                $stepTwo = explode("</content>", $stepOne[1]);
                $tweet = $stepTwo[0];
                $tweet = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $tweet);
                $tweet = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $tweet);
                return $tweet;
            }

            $twitterFeed = file_get_contents($feed);
            echo stripslashes($prefix) . parse_feed($twitterFeed) . stripslashes($suffix);
        ?>​
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try, change you're return to:

```
if(!preg_match("/@(\w+)/", $tweet))
{
    return $tweet;
}
else
{
    return "";
}
```

Comment: that code seems to still be returning the code. I'm guessing I misinterpreted your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you want to get a users latest tweets and then filter out the @'s. I would avoid using the search call and instead focus on the [timeline call](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline).

Attached to each item in the call are these fields

```
 "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
 "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
 "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
 "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
 "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
```

`"in_reply_to_status_id"` and `"in_reply_to_status_id_str"` might remain `null` and it still might be an `@` reply. What your looking for is `"in_reply_to_screen_name"`. If it's filled in with a name it's an `@` reply.

When making the call, simply ignore the items where `in_reply_to_screen_name != null`

Take a look at the [developer console](https://dev.twitter.com/console) as well where you can test, mix & match.

-- Example Code in PHP ☟

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/twitterapi.json", true); 
$decode = json_decode($json, true); //PHP Array output from twitter JSON

$valid = array();
$count = count($decode); //counting the number of status
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    if(!$decode[$i]['in_reply_to_screen_name']){
        array_push($valid, $decode[$i]); 
    }
};

print_r($valid); //tweets that are not @ replies
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Annoyingly I can't get my head around the API. Don't really understand how I'd implement this. I'm guessing I'd need to use the 'exclude_replies=true' field but that's as far as I've got :(

Comment: actually you can make the call as is. I'll update my answer with some basic code.